# React - Next Blog : empty lines show on Browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, class, next.js

I'm working on a blog getting data from Mongo Atlas, the page is in Nextjs 9.5.4 hosted on Vercel.
The blog page uses static props and regeneration

The data is coming in form of a JSON, everything stringified.

```
 return {
      props: {
        articles: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(articles)),
      },
```

The blog posts = articles have all a title, a text and a signature line (author and date)
Some articles have a link and some articles have one or two pictures.
The relevant part of the code is as follows:`

```
{articles.map((article) => (
      <li key={article.id}>
      <h2  className={styles.blogtitle} >{article.title}</h2>
      <p  className={styles.blogtext}>{article.text}</p>
      <img src={article.image1} className={styles.blogimage} alt={article.alt1} ></img>
      <img src={article.image2} className={styles.blogimage} alt={article.alt2} ></img>
      <p>{""}
      <a
       href={article.link} 
      title={article.link}
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer" >
      {article.link}            
      </a>
      </p>
      <p  className={styles.bloginfos}>{article.author}, le {article.date.slice(0,10)} à {article.date.slice(11,16)} h</p>
      </li>
    ))}
```

When I added the pictures and the link, all posts without pictures or links are shown with empty lines for 2 images and one link.
The browser inspector shows that every list entry gets a
`<img class="nextGeneratedName1"> <img class="nextGeneratedName1">`
but otherwise empty tag
and a p tag containing

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

(at least it does not really add an empty link to nowhere in a new tag)

How do I avoid these empty lines? I suppose that the image lines are created by Next adding the class independent of content. But the empty paragraph has no content and no specific class and should not show in html.
The whole project is on GitHub,  [this page is blog.js](https://github.com/helgaParis/animation/blob/master/pages/blog.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a condition check, if the image url is there only then show it, otherwise don't show it e.g. for line 30 of your blog.js file you can do:

```
{article.image1 && <img src={article.image1} className={styles.blogimage} alt={article.alt1} ></img>}
```

and similarly for all the items like a, p etc. that you think can be empty in any case.